# updating dataset c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I have written some logic in C#. Now I need to update it to the already created Dataset.
The Dataset is containing a Table PackageTable. It has two fields, PackageId, and PackagePrice
Now, I want to search the table for certain Packageid, say 'P1' and update the PackagePrice with a new value , say '100'.

Please tell me how to do it with C#.
Please also note that I am not updating it using a textbox or gridview etc.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I see ASP.NET, ObjectDataSource and Dataset. Those are conflicting descriptions, could you be a bit more specific about what you are actually using? Typed or Untyped Dataset? And what version of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
dt.Select("PackageId = 1")[0]["PackagePrice"] = 2;
```

*dt* is your data table, select the rows from it, then set the field value to what you require.

From comments, small example

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("t")
Dim r As DataRow
r = dt.NewRow
r("t") = "aa"
dt.Rows.Add(r)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Dim d As DataTable
d = DataGridView1.DataSource
TextBox1.Text = d.Rows(0)("t")
```

Comment: Select returns an array of DataRow. [0] would be the first row in the array.

Comment: also what is Select? It says'Dataset doesnt contain definition for 'Select''

Comment: Select is used from a Data Table

Comment: @astender, but i dont want to create a new DataTable, I already have a dataset as dataset.xsd and it has the DataTable named Package already. Excuse me if the question is silly, I am new to ASP.Net thanks

Comment: The sample shows how to get the datatable from the DataGridView. Dim d As DataTable    d = DataGridView1.DataSource

Comment: Select is an Extension method (Fx 3.5).